# Para que serve e como usar a propriedade hanging-punctuation do CSS?

Tags: css

Sei que a propriedade `hanging-punctuation` proporciona um controle sobre a tipografia na web, mas não entendi ao certo o que é esse controle e como ele funciona. Além disso vi que a propriedade suporta alguns valores, como `first`, `last`, `force-end` e outros, mas sinceramente não vejo diferença entre eles, nem com exemplos.

### **Dúvidas**

1. O que é o controle que a propriedade oferece sobre a tipografia?
2. Quais são as diferenças entre os principais valores aceitos?
3. Qual a sua utilidade e por que devemos usar (se devemos)?
4. A propriedade é suportada por muitos navegadores?
5. É utilizada? Se sim, como?

Comment: João, nesse link aqui: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hanging-punctuation/, tem uma imagem que explica bem o uso dessa propriedade CSS, e também responde outras perguntas,, como suporte dos navegadores (só o Safari suporta!?), entretanto não entendi muito bem, também, a diferença entre os valores aceitos, mas, no link tem um código de exemplo, então daria pra testar (num browser Safari) para ver quais as diferenças...

Comment: Esse propriedade hoje (19/10/2018) é um rascunho ainda do que deve entrar **um dia** no `css`: [drafts.csswg.org](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#hanging-punctuation-property), e como tal, não é suportado ainda por quase nenhum browser: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hanging-punctuation#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

João Pedro, o `hanging-punctuation` é usado para colocar símbolos como aspas, ponto final e bullets fora da linha do texto, sendo o contrário do indent (o indent empurra o texto para dentro, o hanging-punctuation não afeta o alinhamento do texto em relação ao parágrafo).

Visualmente, o efeito seria:

Sem hanging-punctuation:

Eu gosto de:

- gatos;
- porcos;
- Com `hanging-punctuation:first;` (repare no alinhamento da letra "E" e da letra "g" e não no fato de se tratar de uma lista).

  Eu gosto de:
- gatos;
- porcos;

### Suas dúvidas:

**O que é o controle que a propriedade oferece sobre a tipografia?**
A propriedade oferece controle sobre o alinhamento integral do texto, evitando que sejam inseridos espaços em branco antes (first) ou após o texto (after). A propriedade permite, então, um alinhamento total do texto de acordo com o definido em `text-align`.

**Quais são as diferenças entre os principais valores aceitos?**
O valor "first" irá inserir a pontuação fora da linha do texto e anterior a primeira linha, por sua vez o valor "after" irá inserir a pontuação também fora da linha do texto, mas posterior a última linha.

Quanto ao valor "allow-end", este irá inserir a pontuação fora de todas as linha do texto, posterior a essa linha, apenas se a pontuação não for encaixada de outro modo. Por exemplo, caso a pontuação seja inserida no meio de um parágrafo (e não no início ou no fim), não há porque deslocar a pontuação:

- Exemplo: Então o bardo começou a tocar e todos gritaram "Viva" e aproveitaram a canção.

Por sua vez, o valor "force-end" faz com que a pontuação seja deslocada em todas as linhas, também no final, independente da posição.

**Qual a sua utilidade e por que devemos usar (se devemos)?**
A utilidade é deslocar a pontuação melhorando a estética e o fluxo de leitura. Por não ser suportada por muitos navegadores, bem como por, no caso do "first" ser possível obter o mesmo resultado por meio do `text-indent` (com valor negativo, no caso), não é recomendado o uso.

**A propriedade é suportada por muitos navegadores?
Não, a propriedade é suportada pelo navegador Safari e apenas parcialmente.

**É utilizada? Se sim, como?
Não localizei nada sobre a utilização da propriedade.

Para mais informações, essa é uma ótima fonte sobre CSS e foi ela que utilizei: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/hanging-punctuation/.

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade CSS especifica se um sinal de pontuação deve ser interrompido no início ou no final de uma linha de texto. `hanging-punctuation` A pontuação suspensa pode ser colocada fora da caixa de linha.

```
/* Keyword values */
hanging-punctuation: none;
hanging-punctuation: first;
hanging-punctuation: last;
hanging-punctuation: force-end;
hanging-punctuation: allow-end;

/* Two keywords */
hanging-punctuation: first force-end;
hanging-punctuation: first allow-end;
hanging-punctuation: first last;
hanging-punctuation: last force-end;
hanging-punctuation: last allow-end;

/* Three keywords */
hanging-punctuation: first force-end last;
hanging-punctuation: first allow-end last;

/* Global values */
hanging-punctuation: inherit;
hanging-punctuation: initial;
hanging-punctuation: unset;
```

**Sintaxe**

A propriedade `hanging-punctuation` pode ser especificada com um, dois ou três valores.

A sintaxe de um valor usa qualquer um dos valores de palavra-chave na lista abaixo.
A sintaxe de dois valores usa um dos seguintes:
firstem conjunto com qualquer um de last, allow-endouforce-end
lastem conjunto com qualquer um de first, allow-endouforce-end
A sintaxe de três valores usa um dos seguintes:
first, allow-endelast
first, force-endelast

Exemplo: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQzMVX)

**Compatibilidade**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte da Pesquisa: [MDB Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hanging-punctuation)

Entre na fonte da pesquisa para mais informações.